# How do I correct syntax error when attempting sqlite upsert?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am encountering a SQLite UPSERT syntax error that I am unable to understand/correct. I am referencing the documentation at https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Example code:

```
import sqlite3
cnxn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
# Create a simple table with a Primary Key
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE t (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT)")
# Add a row
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO t(Id,Name) VALUES(1,'Fred')")
# I would expect the following to update Name for Id=1
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO t(Id,Name) VALUES(1,'Sam') ON CONFLICT(Id) DO UPDATE SET Name=excluded.Name")
```

Instead, returns
`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of SQLite are you running? That functionality was only added in 3.24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax was correct. My version of SQLite was not new enough to take advantage of the functionality. Sadly, upgrading SQLite isn't as easy as PIP install --upgrade...

Here are a few handy tips for others that may encounter this:

Finding your current SQLite version

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

Grab the newer version (3.24+ in this case) from the SQLite download site: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Unzip, then save the .dll in [Python install directory]/DLLs folder.